# browsing through nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

this is what an html structure of the webpage looks like:

```
<body>
<form>
 <input type='file'/>
</form>

<div id='list'>
 <div>value here<input id='delete' type='button'/></div>
</div>
</body>
```

i have found javascript code that triggers on 'delete' button click and removes input 'file' element. it uses this piece of code where element is input 'file' mentioned above:

```
deleteButton.onclick=function(){this.parentNode.element.parentNode.removeChild(  
this.parentNode.element );}
```

i am trying to understand logic(rules) behind 'this.parentNode.element' ? why not accessing element directly 'element.parentNode.remove...'

many thanks

Comment: It sounds like the question is how to delete a node. What does browsing have to do with it?

Comment: @mwilcox: I think OP means 'traversing'.

Comment: no, this code works fine. like i said would like to understand it's logic.

Comment: @patrick, thanks, but he's not really traversing either.

Comment: He is traversing the DOM to get to the `parentNode`. That seems to be what he meant in the question by browsing. But yes, `.element` specifically is not traversing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am trying to understand logic(rules) behind 'this.parentNode.element' ?

There's no `element` property on the [`Node`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1950641247), [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-745549614), [`HTMLElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-58190037), or [`HTMLDivElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-22445964) interfaces. So my guess would be that elsewhere in that code, you'll find something that's explicitly adding that property to the element instance of the `div` containing the button. You can do that, add arbitrary properties to element instances. These are frequently called "expando" properties and should be done very, very, *very* carefully.

Comment: in this case element is a variable that holds actual input element i am talking about.. var element=doc...getElem..Id(...);

Comment: @daniel: I realized I'd missed the point about which element was being removed -- at the same time I realized where `element` comes from. :-) Fixed.

Comment: that's it. i have found it!! many thanks.. you have saved my day ;)

Comment: @daniel: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the question, just opinion. It's better avoid constructions like

> this.parentNode.element.parentNode

Because in case when you change your DOM structure, you will need rewrite you JS. So I think it's better to give id attributes to tags, and use next construction to get DOM element:

> document.getElementById('element_id')

or if you will use some js framework (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) you can use even easier construction to get DOM element

> $("#ement_id")

Answer (score 0):

Ok, "removeChild" is a strange method, and quite probably, ill-conceived. It should look like:

```
<div>value here<input id='deleteMe' type='button'/></div>

var node = document.getElementById('deleteMe');
node.remove(); // <--- does not exist, but sure would be nice!!!
```

No, instead we have to do these shenanigans:

```
var node = document.getElementById('deleteMe');
node.parentNode.removeChild(node); // verbose! Convoluted!
```

We have to get the node's parent, call the method, then refer to the node again. This doesn't look like any other DOM methods as far as I recall. The good news is you can make it happen all in one line, chained, like a jQuery method.

You are best served to start over or copy somebody else's code. The use of "this" means it was within an object (or class), referring to other methods or properties within that object. You should stick to non-object variables and functions for now.

Hope that helps.